# My page doesn't record Data with Mysql and apache

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, apache-httpd, mysql

```
intaxing.in/register.php
```

or(website probably don't work)

```
test.intaxing.in/register.php
```

You can look here for the actual working page that did not record anything it just asks again & again for the password I install an app in this order.

```
sudo apt install apache2  php7.3  mariadb-server  mariadb-client php-mysql phpMyAdmin
```

Command updated......

Please let me know if I do wrong somewhere. Or the issue is because of MD5. The same code is working in Window Xampp I use PHP mostly. But if anybody finds an issue I am very helpful to you.

I correct code on PHP 7.3 so now phpMyAdmin doesn't show any error. Install again and again but the result never changes. Working on the latest version of everything.

```
<?php   
ob_start();
session_start();
    
$timezone = date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "punee", "4927","intax");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
}



class Account {

    private $con;
    private $errorArray;
    
    public function __construct($con){
        $this->con = $con;
        $this->errorArray = array();
    }
public function login($un, $pw){
    $pw = md5($pw);
    $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$un' AND password='$pw'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$loginfailed );
        return false;
    }
}

public function Register($un, $fn, $ln, $em, $pw, $pw1, $ph) {
    $this->validateUsername($un);
    $this->validatefirstname($fn);
    $this->validatelastname($ln);
    $this->ValidateEmail($em);
    $this->ValidatePasswrod($pw, $pw1);
    $this->ValidatePhone($ph);
    if(empty($this->errorArray) == true){
    //insert into db
        return $this->insertUserDetails($un, $fn, $ln, $em, $pw, $ph);
        }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public function getError($error) {
    if(!in_array($error, $this->errorArray)) {
        $error = "";
    }
    return "<span class='errorMessage'>$error</span>";
} 

private function insertUserDetails($un, $fn, $ln, $em, $pw, $ph){
    $encryptedPw = md5($pw);
    $profilePic = "include/assets/profile-pic/index.png";
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    
    $result = mysqli_query($this->con, "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$un', '$fn', '$ln', '$em', '$date' , '$encryptedPw', '$profilePic' , '$ph')");
    return $result;
}

    

private function validateUsername($un){
    if(strlen($un) >25 || strlen($un) <5) {
        array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$useridCharacters );
        return;
    }
    
    $checkUsernameQurey = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkUsernameQurey) != 0){
        array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$UsernameTaken);
        return;
    }
}
    ///Database Validation but data not prepare


private function validatefirstname($fn){
    if(strlen($fn) >15 || strlen($fn) <2) {
        array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$firstnameCharacters);
        return;
    }
}

private function validatelastname($ln){
    if(strlen($ln) >15 || strlen($ln) <2) {
        array_push($this->errorArray,Constants::$lastnameCharacters);
        return;
    }
}

private function ValidateEmail($em){
    if(!filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        array_push($this->errorArray,Constants::$emailinvalid);
        return; 
    }
    
    $checkEmailQurey = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT Emailid FROM users WHERE Emailid='$em'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkEmailQurey) != 0){
        array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$emailTaken);
        return;
    }
///check for the email as database prepare
}

private function ValidatePasswrod($pw, $pw1){
    if($pw != $pw1){
        array_push($this->errorArray,Constants::$passwordsDoNotMatch);
        return;
    }
    if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/',$pw)){

    array_push($this->errorArray,Constants::$passwrodNotAlphaNumeric);
    return;
    }
    if(strlen($pw) >10 || strlen($pw) <6) {
    array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$passwordsCharacters);
    return;
        
    }
}

private function ValidatePhone($ph) {
    if(strlen($ph) != 10) {
        array_push($this->errorArray,Constants::$phoneCharacters);
        return;
    }
}

    }


class Constants {

public static $passwordsDoNotMatch = " Your Password don't match";
public static $passwrodNotAlphaNumeric = " Your password can only contain numbers and letters";
public static $passwordsCharacters = " Your Password must be between 6 and 10 characters";
public static $emailinvalid = " Enter a Vaild Email";
public static $useridCharacters = " Your username must be between 5 and 25 characters";
public static $firstnameCharacters = " Your First Name must be between 2 and 15 characters";
public static $lastnameCharacters = " Your Last Name must be between 2 and 15 characters";
public static $phoneCharacters = " Your Mobile Number Should be 10 Digit";
public static $UsernameTaken = " Your Username is already taken";
public static $emailTaken = " Your Email ID is already taken";
public static $loginfailed = "Email or Password Incorrect";
  

    }
$account = new Account($con);

    function sanitizeFormPassword($inputText){
$inputText = strip_tags($inputText);
    return $inputText;
    }

    function sanitizeFormUsername($inputText) {
$inputText = strip_tags($inputText);
$inputText = str_replace(" ","",$inputText);
    return $inputText;
     }
     function sanitizeFormstring($inputText){
$inputText = strip_tags($inputText);
$inputText = str_replace(" ","",$inputText);
$inputText = ucfirst(strtolower($inputText));
return $inputText;
      }
     if(isset($_POST['signupbutton']))
{
    $username = sanitizeFormUsername($_POST['username']);
    $firstname = sanitizeFormstring($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = sanitizeFormstring($_POST['lastname']);
    $Email = sanitizeFormstring($_POST['Email']);
    $Password = sanitizeFormPassword($_POST['Password']);
    $Password1 = sanitizeFormPassword($_POST['Password1']);
    $Phone = sanitizeFormstring($_POST['Phone']);
    
    $wasSuccesfull= $account->register($username, $firstname, $lastname, $Email, $Password, $Password1, $Phone);
    if($wasSuccesfull == true){
        $_SESSION['userLoggedIn']=$username;
        
    header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
      /**
      * @param $name
        */
     function getInputValue($name){
    if(isset ($_POST[$name])){
    echo $_POST[$name];
    }
}
?>
   <html>
   <head>
<tittle> <h2> Register Yourself It just  takes some time </h2></tittle>
    </head>
   <body>
<div id ="inputContainer">
    <form id="loginForm" action="register.php" method="POST">
        <h2> Create Your Account</h2>
        <p>
            <?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$useridCharacters);?> 
            <?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$UsernameTaken);?>
            <label  for="username">Username</label> 
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Puneetxp" Value="<?php echo getInputValue('username');?>"    required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$firstnameCharacters);?>
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Puneet" Value="<?php echo getInputValue('firstname');?>" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$lastnameCharacters);?>
            <label  for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Sharma" Value="<?php echo getInputValue('lastname');?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$emailinvalid);?>
            <?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$emailTaken);?>
            <label for="Email">  Email</label>
            <input  id="Email" name="Email" type="Email" Value="<?php echo getInputValue('Email');?>" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$passwordsDoNotMatch);?>
            <?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$passwrodNotAlphaNumeric);?>
            <?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$passwordsCharacters);?>
            <label for="Possword"> Password</label>
            <input id="Password" name="Password" type="password"  required>
        </p>
        
        <p> 
            <label for="Possword1">Confirm Password</label>
            <input id="Password1" name="Password1" type="password" required>
        </p>
        
        <p>
            <?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$phoneCharacters);?>
            <label for="Phone"> Phone </label>
            <input id="Phone" name="Phone" type="tel"  maxlength="10" Value="<?php echo getInputValue('Phone');?>" required>
        </p>
        <button type="submit" name="signupbutton">Sign UP</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Code Updated as per bob suggestion let hope this time my question is right.

Comment: I don't see the code that didn't work.  Please edit your question to include the code; please don't use a link to some other page.

Comment: thanks bob for guidance I will including my full page code for this. Now it may be little big I don't post it.

Comment: Your question wasn't "wrong," it's just that a link to PHP only shows the generated HTML and not the code.  Without the code, no one can help.

Comment: I haven't spotted the exact problem, but I have looked at the code.  If `mysqli_query` returns **FALSE** you should be displaying `mysqli_error` to see what's happening.  Without having tested this in my own environment, I suspect that the database insert is failing, causing `$wasSuccesfull` to be false.  You have `Value="<?php echo ...` for all form fields except the passwords, so the passwords are empty when the form is redisplayed.

Comment: Having looked at your code, I'd like to point out, gently I hope, two things not related to your problem that also need attention.  You should really be using MySQL prepared queries to guard against SQL injection.  Storing an MD5 hash of a password is only marginally better than storing the plain text.  You can find details here: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->con, "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$un', '$fn', '$ln', '$em', '$date' , '$encryptedPw', '$profilePic' , '$ph')");
    return $result;
```

there is issue '' work on xammp but not other MySQL sever ,Strange. So change it with

```
"INSERT INTO `user`(`username`, `firstname`, `lastName`, `Emailid`, `SignUpDate`, `Password`, `profilePic`, `Phone`) VALUES ( '$un', '$fn', '$ln', '$em', '$date' , '$encryptedPw', '$profilePic' , '$ph')";
```

And it work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the command you used to install the server, try this:

`sudo apt install apache2 php7.3 mariadb-server mariadb-client php-mysql phpmyadmin`

You cannot install multiple packages by seperating their names with `&&`.

Comment: thanks I missed MariaDB-client. I only use && for basically mariadb-server && mariadb-client. I install missing but not help may be they need to install in chain. I will be reinstall raspian again.